# Where do I enter the amount of ETH to be transferred in Remix?

Tags: web3js, remix, ether, ethereumjs

I am new to ethereum world and trying to write a basic ERC 721 smart contract.

[image]

This is my mint function. I am trying to check whether the sender is sending required cost to mint the asset. I am testing my contract in rinkeby testnet.

The question I have is every time I call mint function it throws an error because of the require statement. how do event send ETH to contract to mint the asset. I am using remix and Metamask.

Comment: Try to increase the value here https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200423221341/eight3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use value field of REMIX to pass ether to your function execution. Make sure to add value before calling the function that require payment.

[image]